# ES6 Promise automatic post-processing / cloning results

Tags: javascript, promise

I have a situation where I am building a data layer based on ES6 JS Promises that fetch data from the network. I am caching all Promises internally by the url.

Everything seems to be working fine except one thing. I want to ensure that the data coming out of the network layer is a copy/clone of the data retrieved from the network and I obviously do not want to do that everywhere in the client code that implements Promise's then handlers.

I would like to set this up so then handler automatically gets a copy of the cached data.

To add a twist to this, I would like this to be configurable on a url basis inside the data layer so that some Promises do the extra post-processing copy while others return just the raw result.

Can anyone suggest a proper implementation to accomplish this? I should mention that I would like to get a new copy of the original raw result each time a new client asks for it.

The current simplified pseudo implementation looks like this

```
getCachedData(url){
   if (cache[url]) {
     return cache[url];
   } else {
     var promise = new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
          var data = ...ajax get...;
          resolve(data);
     });
     cache[url] = promise;
}

getCachedData(url).then(result=>{
   here I want the result to be a copy of data I resolved the original promise with.
});
```

Comment: Just use `get(url).then(clone)`? What is your current implementation?

Comment: posted pseudo code of current implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Structure it like this:

```
function retrieveCopiedData () {
    // getDataFromServer is your original Promise
    return getDataFromServer().then(function (value) {
        // use a library of your choice for copying the object.
        return copy(value);
    })}
}
```

This means that all consumers of `retrieveCopiedData` will receive the value returned from  `retrieveCopiedData`'s `then()` handler.

```
retrieveCopiedData().then(function (value) {
    // value is the copy returned from retrieveCopiedData's then handler
})
```

You can add conditional logic to `retrieveCopiedData` as you see fit.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you just want to incorporate the cloning process right in your data layer:

```
getCachedData(url){
    if (!cache[url]) {
        cache[url] = new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
            var data = ...ajax get...;
            resolve(data);
        });
    }
    if (requiresPostProcessing(url))
        return cache[url].then(clone);
    else
        return cache[url];
}
```

Notice that it might be a good idea not to clone the data each time it is retrieved, but to simply [freeze](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) the object that your promise is resolved with.

Comment: Bergi - didn't know about freeze so thanks for the ref. I think I need the copy since the idea is to allow modifications to the objects in the client code ensuring the original object remains intact inside the cache. When I write the modified objects back to the network I invalidate the corresponding cached entry (per url).

Comment: You'll want to use immutable data structures :-) Promises are all about an immutable result, so freezing the object is just consistent. In functional prgroamming, no function should do any modifications to its arguments, but instead create new objects. Freezing just forces your client code to use `clone` when they need it (I'll assume that modifying is rare anyway).